# What is an elegant way to display a four-tabbed table that changes its content based on the tab in HTML/CSS/Native JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

A little bit of background:

I am developing a tracker for my company to which each representative will have access in order to assist with tracking daily statistics such as calls, time spent after a phone call before being available again, revenue, and various sales we are required to make. Each day consists of four "tours", or checkpoints throughout the day at which statistics are recorded. At this point, I have completed the representative tracker portion, but I am having trouble coming up with a way to display the data from each representative in a manager-view page. I'm thinking I'd like to do four tabs to represent each tour and a fifth to view totals. How could I build a table like this using native JavaScript, CSS and HTML? The closest I feel like I have come to a solution is to use `<iframe></iframe>` and display four individual PHP pages inside, but I also think this may be gaudy and awkward.

I started with [this](http://ryanvold.com/tracker/managerpage.php) a while ago; it gives an idea of what I'm looking to make, though it only has four tabs in this example.

Answer (score 0):

a. Use jquery tabs. Great for your case.
b. If you dont want to inmerse in jquery, use the jquery logic:  for each "tab" and with javascript display/hide their contents. You can do this with the whole code in one program (not recomended, but possible), or use ajax calls and different programs. 
For the record: Before ajax times, I used to use iframe for each page with success. Now sounds awkward, but there was a time when it was a valid solution.

Comment: AJAX sounds like a good route; how do you think I should go about in structuring that, if I'm already using AJAX to retrieve data from my database?

Answer (score 0):

I made a pen for doing this without Javascript on modern browsers.

I utilize radios and labels to show different tables. It's using SASS, Haml, and Bootstrap for basic styling, but you can see the compiled HTML and CSS by clicking "(Haml)" and "(SCSS)"

http://codepen.io/jakealbaugh/pen/qsryx/

### EDIT:

Here's a boring fiddle of the compiled CSS and HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/aHjnY/2/

#### Simplified HTML

```
<div class="container">

  <!-- hidden radios. first is checked -->
  <input checked='true' id='radio-1' name='tables' type='radio'>

  <!-- more unchecked inputs for each table here -->
  <!-- id='radio-1' becomes id='radio-2' and so on -->

  <!-- button group for labels -->
  <div class='btn-group'>

    <label for='radio-1'>
      Table 1
    </label>

    <!-- other labels for each input here -->
    <!-- for='radio-1' becomes for='radio-2' and so on -->

  </div>

  <div class='table-container' id='radio-1-table'>
    <table>
      <!-- table content -->
    </table>
  </div>

  <!-- more table containers here -->
  <!-- id='radio-1-table' becomes id='radio-2-table' and so on -->

</div> <!-- close main container -->
```

#### CSS

```
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.table-container {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 2%;
  left: 2%;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  /* hiding all radios */
  display: none;
}

/* do the following for each radio/table/label */

input[type="radio"]#radio-1:checked ~ #radio-1-table {
  /* showing the right table when radio is checked */
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
}
input[type="radio"]#radio-1:checked ~ .btn-group > label[for="radio-1"] {
  /* styling current label */
  color: #333;
  background-color: #ebebeb;
  border-color: #adadad;
}

/* keep going for each radio and table */
```